# Unit testing Spring REST Controller

Tags: spring, junit

I have a Spring boot controller with a method like this:

```
// CREATE
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/accounts")
public ResponseEntity<Account> createAccount(@RequestBody Account account,
                                            @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
                                             UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder) {

    if (!account.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        account = accountService.createAccount(account);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        System.out.println( "Account is null = " + (null == account)); //For debugging
        headers.setLocation(uriBuilder.path("/accounts/{id}").buildAndExpand(account.getId()).toUri());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(account, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

I'm trying to unit test it like this:

```
@Test
public void givenValidAccount_whenCreateAccount_thenSuccessed() throws Exception {
    /// Arrange
    AccountService accountService = mock(AccountService.class);
    UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = mock(UriComponentsBuilder.class);
    AccountController accountController = new AccountController(accountService);
    Account account = new Account("someone@domain.com");

    /// Act
    ResponseEntity<?> createdAccount = accountController.createAccount(account, "", uriBuilder);

    /// Assert
    assertNotNull(createdAccount);
    //assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, createdAccount.getStatusCode());
}
```

but the account is always null. Any idea why is that ?

Comment: `given(accountService.save(account)).willReturn(account);` ?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check my answer in [How to test this method with spring boot test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245033/how-to-test-this-method-with-spring-boot-test/50257922#50257922)

Not only you will find an answer to unit testing controllers but also how to include filters, handlers and interceptors in your test.

Hope this helps,

Jake

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to when clause first of all.

```
  when(accountController.createAccount(account, "", uriBuilder)).then(createAccount); 
  ResponseEntity<?> createdAccount = accountController.createAccount(account, "", uriBuilder);
```